# Clarification of "spirits" on "Devouring Greed" card

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Devouring Greed](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Devouring%20Greed) states:

> As an additional cost to cast Devouring Greed, you may sacrifice any number of Spirits. Target player loses 2 life plus 2 life for each Spirit sacrificed this way. You gain that much life.

Does this only apply to cards that have a type/class of "Creature - Spirit" or does it include cards with a class of "Dragon Spirit" or "Demon Spirit"?

I have tried to research this but can't figure out the correct terms to search for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a little more research and finding some loosely related info on another question here I found the following in the rules.

> 302.3. Creature subtypes are always a single word and are listed after a long dash: "Creature -- Human Soldier," "Artifact Creature -- Golem," and so on. Creature subtypes are also called creature types. Creatures may have multiple subtypes. See rule 205.3m for the complete list of creature types.
>   Example: "Creature -- Goblin Wizard" means the card is a creature with the subtypes Goblin and Wizard.

If a creature has a subtype of "demon spirit", it is a "demon" and a "spirit" which I believe satisfies the "spirits" requirement of "Devouring Greed".

Comment: Note that the subtypes for Tribal are the same as those for Creature. If there were some card with the typeline "Tribal Enchantment - Spirit", it could be sacrificed as part of the additional cost to cast Devouring Greed. (see also Boggart Shenanigans + Goblin Grenade)

Comment: @HaoYe As long as it's a permanent, rather than just a card :)

Answer (score 1):

A card may have several creature types but at least one of them has to be spirit for them to be able to get sacrificed.